# Finding the Omega of a find() in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have this on a HABTM statement:

```
$this->set('usergroups', $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')))));
```

This gets groups that are associated to the user id via a courses_users table.

This works perfectly find, except I also need to find all groups that a user doesn't belong to. How do I get the opposite of the statement above?

I used 'not' as a condition, and it still gave me the same result.

Thanks!

Comment: this is what you get for using [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) for everything

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
$user = $this->User->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    )
));

$otherGroups = $this->Group->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array('id' => Hash::extract($user, '{n}.Group.id'))
    )
));
```

Side Note:  You should really be setting `recursive` to `-1` in your AppModel and not relying on recursive to return additional data.  Instead, use [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).